# Smartphone symbol for pdfLaTeX

Tags: symbols

I want to use a smartphone symbol.

Naturally, I went to [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character), but I wasn't able to find any smartphone look-alike (only old phones, and the mobile one looks like a Blackberry, as opposed to a nowadays standard smartphone).

I was able to find the type of symbol I'm looking for within the answers of these two questions:

1. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173165/27833
2. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223105/27833

But, unfortunately, they both seem to work only with the `fontspec` package... and require either `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`.

Is there any option to get the smartphone symbol for `pdfLaTeX`?

Answer (score 43):

A mobile phone using direct `\pdfliteral` should look like this:

```
\def\mobile{\leavevmode\hbox to7bp{\kern1bp \lower1bp\vbox to12bp{}%
    \pdfliteral{q 0 g 0 G 1 j 2 w 0 0 5 10 re B
       1 g 1 G 1 w .3 1.8 4.4 7 re B 
       1.5 w 2.5 .2 0 .1 re B .3 w 1.7 10 1.6 0 re B Q}%
    \hss}}

Mobile: \mobile
```

Result:
[image: mobile]

**Edit:** Maybe you need scaled version of this. The next version of `\mobile` macro has one parameter which is the scaling coefficient. You can compare with the previous "nonscaled" macro.

```
\newdimen\bpt
\def\mobile#1{\leavevmode 
   \bpt=#1bp \hbox to7\bpt{\kern1\bpt \lower1\bpt\vbox to12\bpt{}%
      \pdfliteral{q #1 0 0 #1 0 0 cm 1 j 2 w 0 0 5 10 re B 
         1 g 1 G  1 w .3 1.8 4.4 7 re B 
         1.5 w 2.5 .2 0 .1 re B .3 w 1.7 10 1.6 0 re B Q}%
      \hss}}

Mobile: \mobile{1}, \mobile{3.2}, \mobile{.2}.
```

Comment: OK fancypants, you are a repeat offender: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234797/is-there-a-ding-symbol-for-a-house/234807#234807, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236287/how-to-draw-many-crossroads/236289#236289.  +1

Comment: For some reason I'm not getting the white circle at the bottom

Comment: ...meaning "I wish I was as talented."

Comment: @MarioS.E. Uh, it seems that Adobe has not so good PDF rasterizer :(. I did try this on PDF viewer based on poppler library. Now, I added a little hack to my code, so Adobe draws the white circle too.

Comment: Ok, some follow-up questions: why `\def` as opposed to `\newcommand`?, and is there any way to restrict the scaling so that the image, no matter what its original size, sits on the baseline and extends up to, but not beyond the line above it (i.e. it will not change the line spacing, nor will it interfere with text above it). --Thanks to @StevenB.Segletes :)

Comment: Why `\def` instead `\newcommand`? Did you see that I ever used `\newcommand`? Never! Because I want my codes are applicable in various TeX macro packages. And if you need to not change line spacing then simply remove the dynamically calculated strut `\lower1\bpt\vbox to12\bpt{}`.

Comment: @wipet  didn't completely understand the last part "And if you need to not change line spacing then simply remove the dynamically calculated strut \lower1\bpt\vbox to12\bpt{}"

Answer (score 13):

Create a document with only one symbol in it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\Huge\faMobilePhone
\end{document}
```

Process it with `lualatex` and `pdfcrop` and `\includegraphics` the result in your document and run `pdflatex` on it.

---

**EDIT1:** Thanks to Heiko Oberdiek
A one-stop solution is to use `standalone` class:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
\Huge\faMobilePhone
\end{document}
```

You run `lualatex` on this file and get a ready cropped pdf file which you can include in your source file with `\includegraphics`.

---

**EDIT2:** `fontinst` can be cumbersome, but it still gives one full control when installing fonts, even in `otf` era.

[image]

Comment: With class `standalone` neither `\pagestyle{empty}` nor `pdfcrop` are needed.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek - I like to use your software but `standalone` is more efficient here :-)  Thanks for the hint; I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: Get your answer a little more polished and I'll accept it :)  Keep in mind (and add examples) of both the creation of the .pdf and the insertion of it inside the main file.  You can get some inspiration from both HeikoOberdiek and Steven B. Segletes

Answer (score 10):

Just find a suitable graphic, e.g., http://trendafrica.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Smartphone-icon.jpg, and place it in a macro that scales it to size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\smartphone{\includegraphics[height=\ht\strutbox]{Smartphone-icon}}
\begin{document}
Text \smartphone
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As of now that's what I'm using as work-around, but I was hoping of a more "native" version i.e., a symbol from a package (like with `fontawsome` in the answer provided by Werner, but for `pdfLaTeX`).  My first try actually consisted in rendering a `TikZ` picture out of the image.

Comment: Is there any special reason to use `\def` as opposed to `newcommand`?  What is the deal with the `height=\ht\strutbox` thing?

Comment: @MarioS.E. Use of `\def` is laziness (I should know better).  The `\ht\strutbox` specification scales the image, no matter what its original size, to something that sits on the baseline and extends *up to*, but not beyond the line above it (i.e. it will not change the line spacing, nor will it interfere with text above it).

Answer (score 6):

You can use with `XeLateX` or `LuaLaTeX` the `\faMobile` command, from package `fontawesome`.

You also can use the `Smartphone Icons`, downloadable from [this site](http://www.fonts2u.com/smartphone-icons.font), which has an extensive set of icons:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

\texttt{Font Awesome: }\vskip2ex

Text text text \faMobilePhone\vskip3ex

\texttt{Smartphone Icons: }\vskip2ex

Text text text {\fontspec{Smartphone Icons}\begin{tabular}[t]{*{10}{c}}
\noalign{\fontspec{Smartphone Icons}}
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j \\
k & l & m &n & o & p & q & r & s & t
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice, but not really an answer to the OP. pdfLaTeX was mandatory here. Maybe you transfer the whole thing to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16586. Would be nice.

Comment: @Larifari: Would be nicer if I created to necessary files for use with LaTeX. I'll try to find a moment in the next few days (but I haven't done such a job for years!).